# What is the correct way to pass a json object from a django view.py to a .js file?

Tags: django, json

I have a json object that i send as a template variable to my html template. If i have an external .js file what is the best way to pass it to it?

I read on another thread to declare the var inside the `<script>` tag in the `<header>`, but that would open up security issues?  What is the standard way?

Thanks,
David

Comment: as a side node, you should typically try to avoid putting <script> tags in the <head> section of your html document ( i assume that is what you're referring to as <header> ) http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a JSON object can be passed to a template like any other template variable. Let us assume that you are passing a queryset as JSON:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**conditions)
    from django.core.serializers import serialize
    json = serialize("json", queryset)
    context = dict(json = json)
    render_to_response(..., context, ...)
```

And inside the template:

```
<script>
    var data = {{ json }};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way is probably making an ajax request (I recommend using jQuery for this) from the javascript to your view to retrieve the json object.

Comment: what if i wanted to load the json object with the webpage load and not make a separate jqueryget?  is this non standard?

thanks again!

Comment: you could also have something like <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/some/view/that/returns/json"></script> and have your view return a string with a javascript content-type like this: "var json = {watever:'your json is here'};"